# What is the best way to break a while loop with a callback function?

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, callback, arduino

Although I'm using the Arduino IDE the device running the code is an ESP8266.

I'm sure I have mis-structured my code but I'm unsure of the best method, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

**To boil down the scenario I have to a basic example:**

My main loop() function simply runs a callback() function (PubSubClient MQTT) on each pass. This callback function first sets a global boolean variable "run" to false and then will do 1 of 3 things:

1. If '1' is received it will run a function called action1().
2. If '2' is received it will run a function called action2().
3. If '3' is receievd it will print a line to Serial.
4. If anything else or nothing is received it will do nothing.

Both action1() and action2() functions are loops that look something like this:

```
void action1() {
  run = true;             // Do this once to start the loop
  while (run == true) {
    // Do some stuff
    callback();           // To check for new messages
  }
}
```

**Here's the issue:**

If action1() is running and the callback() recieves '3' all is ok. The callback will set the "run" variable to false, print the line to Serial and then return to the action1() loop which will break and the whole thing goes back to loop().

If however action1() is running and the callback() receives the command to start action2(), action2() will start and action1() is simply paused waiting to be returned to.

I think therefore flicking back and forth between action1() and action2() may be causing memory issues as the loops are stacking up on top of each other. I see the device crashing if I do this enough.

I figure perhaps the callback() needs to 'queue' action1() or action2() and then let the main loop() run them? This way we would always go back to the main loop() thus ending all others. I'm sure there's a better solution though.

Comment: Seems like `main` should have the one-and-only loop. And the callback should return a value between 0 and 3 and let `main` handle the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code structure is indeed not correct:

- the call to the callback will pile up.  If you have many callback events, you might end-up with a stack overflow.
- the use a global `run` variable makes the `callback()` non re-entrant, which might cause a premature end of the processing.

In fact, you'd better opt for an event-loop, which would as you already pointed out base on a queue:

- the `callback()` would be called only when ai item item is received and it would queue the item and return.
- your main loop would at each iteration just read something from the queue if it's available, and call the right action.
- If necessary, you could also call some polling function if it would be required.
- If necessary you could also call an output function to reflect the current state.

It's not clear if the main loop would run forever, or only until some special input is received, or just until the queue is empty.  Up to you to decide.

I don't know how your callback is triggered in the arduino model.  But if it interrupts the running process, you'd need also to make sure that there is no race condition on the queue, for example with a lock.

Answer (score 0):

while loops are a bad design in general. There's the loop() function, which you should use.

Rememer the last received valid command and call the corresponding `action_x()` repeatedly. This function "does some stuff" and returns pretty fast, so you do not need that `callback()`.

Often it's convenient, if `action_x()` returns a status to signal that it has finished the task.